# How to pass .phtml file variable to another module .phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I am new in the magento. If anyone have idea how to do this then please let me know.
I have two files in different module in in that two .phtml file will be there.
From First .phtml file to another .phtml file i want pass array variable
I am not getting how to pass that.

First file path as follows with php variable:

```
/var/www/html/MyProject/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Lof_CustomerMembership/templates/customer/membership/transactions.phtml
```

In this file i have $transaction variable that i want to send another info.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address $block */

$helper = $this->helper("Lof\CustomerMembership\Helper\Data");
$transactions = $block->getTransactions();
$address=$block->getPrimaryBillingAddress();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerId =$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
 $activeOrNot="";
?>
```

Another file path will be:

```
/var/www/html/MyProject/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Magedelight_SMSProfile/templates/account/dashboard/info.php
```

In the info.php file i want that $transactions array variable

Anyone have idea how to do this then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want `$transactions = $block->getTransactions();` in another PHTML File
What we can do

1. Create a view model (recommended) and check the block `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address` and figure out how `getTransactions()` is defined and do the same in the view model and then attach that view model with the Magedelight block using layout
   https://devhooks.in/blog/how-to-use-viewmodels-in-magento2 - how to create view model
2. Create a helper and do mention in point 1

Thanks and Happy coding

Comment: Yes you understand my questions. But getting your answer. I am just new in the magento2 . Can u explain more..